# How to install apt-get?

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, apt

I need to install `apt-get` for terminal because then I have to install `raspi-config` to launch my raspberry pi. I'm relatively a beginner so I would appreciate it if you would type the exact code for me. *I do have apt*

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install raspi-config' Is that what you're asking for ?

Comment: How do you know apt-get is not installed or working?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: No when I try "sudo apt-get install raspi-config" it says that the apt-get command not found

Comment: I am using OS X 10.7.5

Comment: @Raspberry.Pi [*Duplicate?*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80711/136880). `apt` is a package manager for opensource software and is not available for OS X afaik.

Comment: Ok so if I install home-brew can I use that?

Comment: Apologies for going on a tangent but given the context I'm really curious to know now what is the "apt" that you have installed? Since it's clearly not related to apt-get...

Comment: It's the one on all the macs.

Comment: Why do you want to run `raspi-config` on your Mac?

Answer (score 0):

So obviously you are not really knowing what you are doing, this is not a insult. If you are a total beginner try to look into [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) image for raspberry.

Installation and rest is easy and widely documented. Because you will face some more problems and if the you start from scratch it makes it pretty hard for you to make progress.